# How to install e(fx)clipse 3.4.1 in Eclipse with Java 11?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, java-11, efxclipse

I am using the 4.9.0 Version of the Eclipse IDE with a JDK 11 and was trying to install the [e(fx)clipse 3.4.1](https://projects.eclipse.org/projects/technology.efxclipse) Plugin. Somehow it could not find all resources, to install it properly and I got the following message:

[Error Message](https://github.com/Django987/javaSandbox/blob/master/errorMessage.txt)

Are the components with those versions not compatible?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Try installing version (3.4.1) release from this [Update site](https://download.eclipse.org/efxclipse/updates-released/3.4.1/site/).

Also check [this issue on GitHub](https://github.com/eclipse-efx/efxclipse-eclipse/issues/42).